# How to solve $\int_{-2}^2 (x + \sqrt{16-4x^2}) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral: $\int_{-2}^2 (x + \sqrt{16-4x^2}) dx$ and I can't solve it completely by myself, so I would really appreciate some help.
I start like this:
$\int_{-2}^2 (x + \sqrt{16-4x^2}) dx$
$\int_{-2}^2 (x) dx + \int_{-2}^2 (\sqrt{16-4x^2}) dx$
$\int_{-2}^2 (x) dx + 2 \int_{-2}^2 (\sqrt{4-x^2}) dx$
$[\frac{x^2}{2}] + 2 [\frac{2(4-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{3(-2x)}]$
$[\frac{x^2}{2}] + 2 [\frac{(4-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{-3x}]$
I feel like this is too complicated for what I'm trying to do. Is there a better way to solve this or should I just continue with this?

Comment: think that the formula in square root represent a circle with radius $2$, it may help you

Comment: $\frac{2(4-x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}{3(-2x)}$ is an anti-derivative of $\sqrt {4-x^{2}}$.

Comment: If you are learning trigonometric substitution, try something like $x=4\sin(y)^2$

Comment: @geetha290krm That is what I wrote

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say it is NOT an anti-derivative of $\sqrt {4-x^{2}}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,
$$\begin{align}I & = \int_{-2}^2(x +  \sqrt{16 - 4x^2}) \ dx \\& = \int _{-2}^2 (x )\ dx + \int_{-2}^2 \sqrt{16 -4x^2}\ dx
\\& = 0 + 2\int_{0}^2 \sqrt{16 - 4x^2}\ dx \tag{1}
\\& = 2\cdot 2\int_{0}^2\sqrt{4 - x^2}\ dx
\\& = 4 \int _{0}^2 \sqrt{4 - x^2}\ dx
\\& = 4\left(\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} + \frac{4}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2_0 \tag{2}
\\& = 4\left(\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2} + 2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)^2_0
\\& = 4\left(\frac{2}{2}\sqrt{4-4} + 2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{2}\right)\right)
 - 4\left(\frac{0}{2}\sqrt{4-0} + 2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{0}{2}\right)\right)
\\& = 4(0+ 2\sin^{-1}(1)) - 4(0 + 2\sin^{-1}(0))
\\& = 4\pi \tag{3}\\
\end{align}$$

> $(1)$ There is a property of integrals of the form $\int_{-a}^{a} f(x)\ dx$. $$\int_{-a}^a f(x)\ dx = \begin{cases} \displaystyle2\int_0^a f(x) \ dx, \quad \text{if the function is  even.}\\ \displaystyle 0, \qquad\qquad \qquad\text{if the function is odd.} \end{cases} $$
> $(2)$ It is advisable to learn the anti-derivative of $\int \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}\ dx$ by heart. And if you apply the method of trig. substitution, you will be deriving this result. $$\int\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} \ dx = \frac{x}{2}\sqrt{a^2 - x^2} + \frac{a^2}{2} \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + C $$
> $(3)$ $\sin^{-1}(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\sin^{-1}(0) = 0.$

Comment: Just inserting the parametrization $x=2\sin t$, $t\in[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$ would give a shorter calculation.